# Read an excel file in the C# console

Tags: c#, excel, replace, converters

I need to read an Excel file, I did everything according to the video tutorial and there are no differences in the code, but when I run the code, the line is not executed:

```
excelTable[rowIndex - 1, i] = Convert.ToDouble(list[i].Replace('.', ','));
```

Here is the entire corresponding part of the code:

```
double[,]? excelTable;
int totalRows = 0;
int totalColumns = 0;
ExcelPackage excelFile = new ExcelPackage(@"D:\telegram bot_d\Excel_Ankets.xlsx");
List();

async Task List()
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    
    totalRows = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
    totalColumns = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
    excelTable = new double[totalRows, totalColumns];

    for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= totalRows; rowIndex++)
        {

        IEnumerable<string> row = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1, rowIndex, totalColumns].Select(c => c.Value == null ? string.Empty : c.Value.ToString());
        List<string> list = row.ToList<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            excelTable[rowIndex - 1, i] = Convert.ToDouble(list[i].Replace('.', ','));
            Console.WriteLine("2"); 
        }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < totalColumns; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(excelTable[i, j]));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
        return;
    }
```

in the future, I plan to display specific values ​​for variables and write a table through the Telegram bot

I checked the video tutorial several times and searched more than 5 forums, but I couldn't find anything

Comment: how do you determine the line isn't executed? Did you use your debugger and went line by line?

Comment: Did you debug your application?

Comment: You never `await` your method `List();` - there for try `await List();`

Comment: I notice the code is replacing dots with commas in the input string before it converts it to a double. That would only make sense in some locations, and could vary by local system and possibly by document.

Comment: I inserted two Console.Writeline, the first one executes and the second one doesn't

Comment: my console says:
Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<<Main>$>g__List|0>d.MoveNext() in D:\telegram bot_d\telegram bot\telegram bot\Program.cs:line 47
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in D:\telegram bot_d\telegram bot\telegram bot\Program.cs:line 41
   at Program.<Main>(String[] args)

does that mean i spelled the path wrong? If so, I think I wrote it correctly...